# html5 banner using Google Web Designer

Tags: google, html5, google-ads, banners

I have create a html5 banner using Google Web Designer following pretty much all the guidelines (https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/3261498?hl=en&ref_topic=3261495&rd=1).

I published it locally and uploaded to google adwords campaign as an Image add. In my banner there is a simple form for the user to enter basic details and submit it. So i have just one event on submit button. All good so far. After i uploaded the banner to google adwords, when i tested the banner the whole banner is clickable for some reason. Somehow google is appending a click event on the whole banner.

But according to docs (https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/176108?hl=en)

"HTML5 ads that are not created in Google Web Designer are, by default, clickable on the entire area of the ad."
I used google web designer for this specific reason still i see the entire area clickable. Any ideas or suggestions or references would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen a Google Adwords ad that wasn't full coverage click... out of interest care to show where you read you can setup ads non-full coverage clicks like buttons and such...

Comment: Ok the base assumption of mine was i will use a image ad with a form so i could gather information about user. So  please correct me, the image ads are not used similarly like flash banners where we can gather data

Comment: Adwords as far as I know supports HTML5 animations but as far as 'click' interactions they only support the entrie region, they want money on simple clicks not interactions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [similar question and answer I found on the Adwords Community](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Advanced-Features/HTML5-Display-Ad-with-a-form/td-p/407213) forum:

> Just wanted to let your know that HTML5 or any display ad on AdWords
> cannot be used with form elements in it. As you said, any click on the
> HTML5 ads will redirect you to the landing page plus any display ads
> that mimic a feature that they cannot actually perform (i.e. form fill
> actions) will eventually get disapproved and your account may be
> penalized for it.
>
> Also, the ad that you mentioned had form fields was infact an
> engagement ad and not an flash ad. Here are more details on Engagement
> ads:
> http://adwords.blogspot.in/2013/12/engagement-ads-for-everyone.html
>
> Steps on how to create Engagement ads:
> https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3265312?hl=en
>
> Ad Policies:
> https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/6135143?hl=en